# Python: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompressobj'

Tags: python, excel, ubuntu-14.04, zlib, xlrd

I'm using Python 2.7.11 on Ubuntu.

I'm trying to open an Excel file (.xlsx) in Python using `xlrd` package. However I get the following error when I try to use the `open_workbook()` function from the package to open my Excel file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "TileInserter.py", line 15, in <module>
        book = open_workbook(sheetPath, on_demand=True)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 422, in open_workbook
        ragged_rows=ragged_rows,

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 761, in open_workbook_2007_xml
        zflo = zf.open(component_names['xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels'])

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 1010, in open
        close_fileobj=should_close)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 526, in __init__
        self._decompressor = zlib.decompressobj(-15)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompressobj'
```

I tried to google the cause of this error and found that this could happen if the `zlib` library is not installed. But when I checked using PHP's `phpinfo()` function, it shows that `zlib` is installed. And that too the latest version (version 1.2.8).

So I'm kinda stuck now. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

**EDIT**: My actual code in `TileInserter.py` goes like this (`TileInserter.py` and `TileList.xlsx` being in the same directory):

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

sheetPath = "TileList.xlsx"
#some more variables

#Open Excel file
book = open_workbook(sheetPath, on_demand=True)
for name in book.sheet_names():
    if name.endswith('1'):
        sheet = book.sheet_by_name(name)
```

Comment: Please post your actual code

Answer (score 1):

I see on http://www.python-excel.org/ that there's a library `openpyxl` that is recommended for working with *.xlsx* files. This may be what you need instead of `xlrd`.

Comment: Well, I tried to open a `.xls` document instead of `.xlsx` and it did open without any problems. So thanks for pointing that out!

But according to this thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371163/reading-xlsx-files-using-python) , `.xlsx` support was added to `xlrd` around 6years ago and I'm using the latest version (0.9.4 as of now) of it too.

Comment: So thanks for pointing that out. I've upvoted your answer since it solves my problem but I'll wait for an answer that actually answers the question to give the checkmark.